# How to get return values when calling Objective-C functions from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, objective-c, ios

I use JSBridge to call Objective-C functions from JavaScript. I see no way to get the results back into the JavaScript without calling another function (from objc) or busy waiting in JavaScript on a variable to change.

What is the recommended way to get results from calling objc functions from JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to get results from calls to the JSBridge. All one can do is put a callback methodname in and have it called with the result as a parameter.